# Tomcat enabling SSL for JDBC during startup

Tags: ssl, jdbc, tomcat6

During Tomcat6 startup, catalina logs shows the below output and it looks like its trying to enable SSL for JDBC. This was not happening before and started seeing this output all of a sudden. I don't remember changing anything in the enviornment.
Any idea why Tomcat is trying to enable SSL for JDBC? Tomcat is using JRE6.

```
Oct 11, 2016 10:18:26 AM com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel enableSSL
INFO: java.security path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\security
Security providers: [SUN version 1.6, SunRsaSign version 1.5, SunJSSE version 1.6, SunJCE version 1.6, SunJGSS version 1.0, SunSASL version 1.5, XMLDSig version 1.0, SunPCSC version 1.6, SunMSCAPI version 1.6]
SSLContext provider info: Sun JSSE provider(PKCS12, SunX509 key/trust factories, SSLv3, TLSv1)
SSLContext provider services:
[SunJSSE: KeyFactory.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyFactory
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: KeyPairGenerator.RSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSAKeyPairGenerator
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD2withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD2withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.2, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.2]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$MD5withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.4, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.4]
, SunJSSE: Signature.SHA1withRSA -> sun.security.rsa.RSASignature$SHA1withRSA
  aliases: [1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, OID.1.2.840.113549.1.1.5, 1.3.14.3.2.29, OID.1.3.14.3.2.29]
, SunJSSE: Signature.MD5andSHA1withRSA -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.RSASignature
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$SunX509
, SunJSSE: KeyManagerFactory.NewSunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.KeyManagerFactoryImpl$X509
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.SunX509 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$SimpleFactory
, SunJSSE: TrustManagerFactory.PKIX -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.TrustManagerFactoryImpl$PKIXFactory
  aliases: [SunPKIX, X509, X.509]
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSL -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.SSLv3 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLS -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.TLSv1 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: SSLContext.Default -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.DefaultSSLContextImpl
, SunJSSE: KeyStore.PKCS12 -> com.sun.net.ssl.internal.pkcs12.PKCS12KeyStore
]
java.ext.dirs: C:\Program Files\Java\jre6\lib\ext;C:\Windows\Sun\Java\lib\ext
```

There is also a warning related to connection pool initialization

```
Oct 11, 2016 10:18:26 AM org.apache.naming.NamingContext lookup
WARNING: Unexpected exception resolving reference
org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.SQLNestedException: Error preloading the connection pool
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1398)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.getLogWriter(BasicDataSource.java:1098)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.createDataSource(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:350)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(BasicDataSourceFactory.java:156)
at org.moss.jdj.dbcp.EncryptedDataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(EncryptedDataSourceFactory.java:25)
............
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.start(Bootstrap.java:289)
at org.apache.catalina.startup.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:414)
Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: The driver could not establish a secure connection to SQL Server by using Secure Sockets Layer (SSL) encryption. Error: "SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.".
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.terminate(SQLServerConnection.java:1352)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1533)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:1042)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:817)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:700)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:842)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.DriverConnectionFactory.createConnection(DriverConnectionFactory.java:38)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.PoolableConnectionFactory.makeObject(PoolableConnectionFactory.java:582)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.pool.impl.GenericObjectPool.addObject(GenericObjectPool.java:1617)
at org.apache.tomcat.dbcp.dbcp.BasicDataSource.createDataSource(BasicDataSource.java:1395)
... 37 more
Caused by: java.io.IOException: SQL Server returned an incomplete response. The connection has been closed.
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.ensureSSLPayload(IOBuffer.java:607)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:664)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$SSLHandshakeInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:656)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.readInternal(IOBuffer.java:851)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel$ProxyInputStream.read(IOBuffer.java:839)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.performInitialHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.sun.net.ssl.internal.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.startHandshake(Unknown Source)
at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSChannel.enableSSL(IOBuffer.java:1483)
... 45 more
```

Comment: Are you seeing any problems because of this? Are you sure that your database connection hasn't changed from `http` to `https`?

Comment: There is no change in the JDBC URL. Not sure if it is because of the above error, but there is a warning in the Catalina logs about Tomcat not able to initialize the connection pool.

Comment: Is the data source defined as a Resource in your context.xml? And have you changed that?

Comment: yes, it's defined as a resource in my server.xml and nothing has changed in that

Comment: Did you resolve this?